# Android Layout, soft keyboard pushes screen elements out of alignment when layout is coupled with Tabhost

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tabhost

I've tried toggling the Window soft input mode in the manifest to no avail.  Whenever I tap the edittext and the soft keyboard comes up, it squishes my text input as well as the button.

here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutRoot"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".12" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/topBarImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/top_banner2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/NameText"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight=".60"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:text="Name" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/name_picker"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_weight=".10"
            android:onClick="doLaunchContactPicker"
            android:text="+" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:text="Add Diner" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight=".55"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/userListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="#7A1962"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight=".15"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because of the LinearLayout. Before defining the LinearLayout contain the layout within a RelativeLayout. This worked for me.

Comment: i am using it in the relative layout only.. even though i am getting same problem.. Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the api-demos ? 
go there to app->activity->soft input modes :
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/SoftInputModes.html

they have multiple ways to handle the way that the softkeyboard appears.